# iPhone - start multiple instances of AVAudioPlayer simultaneously

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

I am using multiple instances of AVAudioPlayer to play multiple audio files simultaneously. I run a loop to start playing the audio files (prepareToPlay is called beforehand and the loop only makes a call to the play method)

But invariably, one of the players does not play in sync. How can I ensure that all the 4 players start playing audio simultaneously?

Thanks.

Comment: I am getting a lag of 0.8 seconds! Please help. even this lag is very audible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. AVAudioPlayer doesn't provide any mechanism for fine-grained control of start time. The `currentTime` property sets the point in the file to read from, it doesn't guarantee when the AVAudioPlayer instance will start playing in system time, which is what you need to sync multiple audio streams.

When I need this behavior, I use the RemoteIO Audio Unit + the 3D Mixer Audio Unit + ExtAudioFile.

*EDIT*

Note that as of iOS 4, you can synchronize multiple `AVAudioPlayer` instances using `playAtTime:`

Comment: I also want to provide an option for seeking. Can you point me to some samples which would explain the use of 3D Mixer? And wouldn't it create a lag before starting to play while the audio files are being mixed?

Comment: Here's Apple's sample code for the mixer AU:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/iPhoneMultichannelMixerTest/index.html

Comment: As for lag/latency, the mixer doesn't introduce any additional latency. If the current session's buffer size is 128 samples, for example, you'll hear audio about 3ms after you start feeding it to the mixer's callback, just as you would if you fed it straight to the RemoteIO's callback.

Comment: That's odd, since the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) talk about how you can "Play multiple sounds simultaneously, one sound per audio player, with precise synchronization". Perhaps you need to call `playAtTime:` e.g. `[myAudioPlayer playAtTime: myAudioPlayer.deviceCurrentTime + playbackDelay];`

Comment: Check the date on that answer, fully 5 months before iOS 4 (where `playAtTime` made its first appearance) was even announced. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Gotcha. Can you update the content to point to my answer, since it's no longer correct?

Answer (score 3):

The [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) talk about how you can "Play multiple sounds simultaneously, one sound per audio player, with precise synchronization". Perhaps you need to call `playAtTime:` e.g. `[myAudioPlayer playAtTime: myAudioPlayer.deviceCurrentTime + playbackDelay];`

In fact, the [Apple docs for playAtTime:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/playAtTime%3a) contain the following code snippet:

```
NSTimeInterval shortStartDelay = 0.01;            // seconds
NSTimeInterval now = player.deviceCurrentTime;

[player       playAtTime: now + shortStartDelay];
[secondPlayer playAtTime: now + shortStartDelay];
```

They should play simultaneously (assuming you choose a large enough value for `shortStartDelay` -- not so soon that it happens before this thread returns or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

This code segment of mine allows you to do this as long as you don't have to do it instantly.  You can pass in the targetTime as a timestamp for when you want to hear the sounds.  The trick is to make use of time-stamps and the delay functionality of NSObject.  Also, it utilizes the fact that it takes way less time to change the volume of the player than it does to change the current time.  Should work almost perfectly precisely.

```
- (void) moveTrackPlayerTo:(double) timeInSong atTime:(double) targetTime {
 [trackPlayer play];
 trackPlayer.volume = 0;

 double timeOrig = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
 double delay = targetTime - CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
 [self performSelector:@selector(volumeTo:) 
      withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:single.GLTrackVolume] 
      afterDelay:delay];
 trackPlayer.currentTime = timeInSong - delay - (CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - timeOrig);
}

- (void) volumeTo:(NSNumber *) volNumb {
 trackPlayer.volume = [volNumb floatValue];
}
```

Comment: What is `single.GLTrackVolume`?

Comment: `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` doesn't guarantee precise enough timing for use with synchronizing audio. It schedules callbacks on the thread's run loop and runs them "as soon as possible" but not down to the 1/44100th of a second :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set same **[currentTime](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/currentTime)** property value for every AVAudioPlayer object.

Comment: The currentTime for all is set to 0.

Comment: `currentTime` is the time *relative to the beginning of the sample* where it will start playing *when* it starts playing -- should be called `offset` or something -- so it won't help synchronize two players